# I was wondering if you'd like to come to the cinema with me this evening? Is the use of a question mark correct?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

I wonder if we need to use a question mark following "I wonder" for requesting something.

For example: I was wondering if you'd like to come to the cinema with me this evening?

Is using the question mark correct here?

Comment: No. It's not a question but a statement.

Comment: If you're looking for a "Yes" answer (and possibly dreading a "No"), you're soliciting a reply and the question mark is certainly justified. [Declarative questions](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-declarative-question-1690372) take question marks. If you're just making a statement: "What are you thinking about?  ...  "I was wondering if you'd like to come to the cinema with me this evening." the question mark is inappropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, but I wouldn't, since the question "I was wondering if you'd like to come to the cinema with me this evening" is indirect. You can give it the overt form of a question by using auxiliary inversion with rising intonation: "I was wondering would you like to come to the cinema with me this evening?", and then the question mark is okay.